# Filter by attribute with D3

Tags: d3.js

I couldn't find an answer to a (hopefully) very easy question. I use filtering like in this chord diagram example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006:

```
.filter(function(d) { return d.source.index != i && d.target.index != i; })
```

What I need now is to filter only those connections with, let's say, an orange fill. Is there something like

```
.filter(style('fill') == 'orange')
```

that works? Any advice highly appreciated.

Comment: Something like: `.filter(function(d){ return d3.select(this).style('fill') == 'orange' })`?

Comment: You can also do this directly with a selector, e.g. `d3.selectAll("path[fill=orange]")`.

Comment: if then else method on a mdml's answer. You may also want to compete the values outside of .filter() for better organization.

Answer (score 7):

To search everything with fill = orange, you can do:

```
svg.selectAll('path[style = "fill: orange;"]')
```

If you want to limit the search to a particular element type, for example "rect", you can do:

```
svg.selectAll('rect[style = "fill: orange;"]')
```

Comment: what about for more complex predicates, like a "g" whose id starts with "fromLondon-", such that it selects g nodes whose id might be "fromLondon-toNewYork", "fromLondon-toParis"?